# how to find out which message to send by postmessage in autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I have this code that opens a test file I have in editpad. I have spy++ to monitor messages sent within windows.
I cant make out from the monitored messages what I need to send command to open a specific menu like file and click an option within it.
my final goal is to be able to turn any sequence of actions into a hot key. am I going the wrong way about it?

the code I have

+j::Run C:\Program Files\Just Great Software\EditPad Lite 7\EditPadLite7.exe "E:\xxx"

Comment: I don't think you can do anything useful this way, why not turn the sequence of keys that created the action into a hotkey?

Comment: not all sequences of actions are keys. in some you have to open a menu. i dont want to use mouse click as that isnt dependable.